# QT QgraphicsScene mouse press event not registered

Tags: qt, drawing, mouse, line

I am starting up in QT for a simple drawing application and i have problem in with the mouse event handles of QGraphicsView.

Here is a summary of the code (please bear in mind this is made to get the basic operation right only. The main just creates a QMainWindow-like element that has the following constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    myCanvas = new GraphicsView;
    myCanvas -> sizeGS(0, 0, 800, 600);
    setCentralWidget(myCanvas -> getView());
    resize(800,600);
}
```

my Canvas belongs to the class derived from QGraphicsView where any mouse press event is not registered at all.

```
class GraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GraphicsView(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~GraphicsView(){};
    void sizeGS(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
    QGraphicsView* getView() {return canvasView;};

protected:
    operationType currentOperation;

private:
    static const int exMaxPolygonSize = 10;

    QGraphicsScene *canvasScene;
    QGraphicsView *canvasView;

    std::vector<QPointF> mousePos;
    QList<QGraphicsItem *> draftedItems;
    QPointF topLeft;
    QPointF bottomRight;

    void resetLineDrawing();
    void completeDrawing();
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent);
};
```

and the key parts of the class are the following two functions:

```
GraphicsView::GraphicsView(QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsView()
{
canvasScene = new QGraphicsScene;
canvasView = new QGraphicsView(canvasScene);
mousePos.reserve(exMaxPolygonSize);
//canvasView->setMouseTracking(true);
canvasView->setRenderHints( QPainter::Antialiasing );

qDebug() << "constructor is ok";
}

void GraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
qDebug() << "mouse grabbed!";
};
```

The mousePressEvent have been tried also with test on the buttons and so on like with no difference.

Any help to understand what is that i am missing would help. 
I am using QT5.2 on OSX.

Thanks

EDIT: This code is for under standing how to control the mouse events for a QGView being central widget of a QMainWindow.

Comment: what is the point to embed a QGraphicsView (canvasView) inside a QGraphicsView (GraphicsView) ? Only one is needed imo

Comment: Not sure I follow you. I have a class,  lame name,  of which I inly have QGV and which will contains several actions and vars.

Comment: SOLVED: I found my own error, i needed to propagate de mousepressevent from the MainWidow class that was capturing it.

Comment: if you mean propagate from MainWindow to GraphicsView class, i'm pretty sure it's not THE solution, just a weak workaround

Comment: Correct. I now realise i had indeed two views.

Comment: please mark answer as accepted if it helped solving your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GraphicsView` class inherits `QGraphicsView`, which is not used in your code.
Try the following : in the main window constructor, use your `GraphicsView` instance directly as a `QGraphicsView` :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    myCanvas = new GraphicsView;
    //myCanvas -> sizeGS(0, 0, 800, 600);
    setCentralWidget(myCanvas);
    resize(800,600);
}
```

In `GraphicsView` header, do not embed another `QGraphicsView` ! (I comment useless lines out)

```
class GraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GraphicsView(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~GraphicsView(){};
    //void sizeGS(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
    //QGraphicsView* getView() {return canvasView;};

protected:
    operationType currentOperation;

private:
    static const int exMaxPolygonSize = 10;

    QGraphicsScene *canvasScene;
    //QGraphicsView *canvasView;

    std::vector<QPointF> mousePos;
    QList<QGraphicsItem *> draftedItems;
    QPointF topLeft;
    QPointF bottomRight;

    void resetLineDrawing();
    void completeDrawing();
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent);
};
```

Finally, in your GraphicsView cpp file, just use it as expected :

```
GraphicsView::GraphicsView(QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsView()
{
canvasScene = new QGraphicsScene;
//canvasView = new QGraphicsView(canvasScene); 
this->setScene(canvasScene); // here you associate the scene with the view
setSceneRect(0, 0, 800, 600); // override your sizeGS() call

mousePos.reserve(exMaxPolygonSize);
//canvasView->setMouseTracking(true);
canvasView->setRenderHints( QPainter::Antialiasing );

qDebug() << "constructor is ok";
}

void GraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
qDebug() << "mouse grabbed!";
};
```

Now you should see `mousePressEvents`, because you actually use the intended `GraphicsView`

Comment: Thanks! I now see that i got it wrong as when making a child the class has a alredy a view element. I was working as if the original class was not derived by QGraphicsView. Silly me.